# Connecting android app with application on a pc

Tags: android, bluetooth, usb

I am currently trying to write an android App that is connected to a application running on a pc (even though windows is preferred linux would be ok, too) via either USB or Bluetooth. Right now I'm not really sure how far this is possible. As far as I understand the USB Android API, I can not really use USB to talk to another application. Only raw file exchange seems to be possible. The Bluetooth idea seems a lot more feasible as I see it. I'd write a bluetooth server for the PC and connect to it via a Bluetooth client written via Android API. Point is, is that possible with windows? Has anyone seen any examples for what I am looking for? All I can find for USB is teethering which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are android applications which allow you to use your mobile's touchscreen act like a touch pad which can be used to control your pc or laptop via bluetooth or wifi connection just like you are using your laptop's touch pad. PremoteDroid, RemoteDroid, Gmote etc.. to name a few (or only these are available i guess!).

But to do so you also need to develop a server application which will run on the device you wish to control and help u make connection between your mobile and the device. I have used PremoteDroid and RemoteDroid and they both work well on my laptop which runs windows 7. You can even add keyboard functionality.

PremoteDroid is openly available here: http://code.google.com/p/premotedroid/

Comment: Thanks, as far as I can see it, seems to be a good starting point for me and it confirms what I intended to do with the Bluetooth interface. But I'm still open for more input, especially for the USB part.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Bluetooth server application on my Mac that I use to test an Android app I'm writing.  The app will eventually be used to communicate with a device with a microcontroller and bluetooth modem, but I needed a way to test the app in the absence of that device.  The server app is written in Java, so I think it should work on a PC (and almost certainly in Linux).

I'm happy to share the code with you--I found it somewhere on the Internet (though I can't seem to figure out where now) and modified it as I needed to.  It uses the BlueCove library, and is only about 60 lines, including several imports (and the code I commented out but didn't bother deleting :).  I also have a Bluetooth client program on my Mac, since my app also has server functionality.

I have never tried to do anything like this using USB.